# open a site every 15 seconds with different IP

Tags: python, python-2.7

sorry if my english is not good.
I wanna write a program that can open the site every 15 seconds. But do it with a different IP. That means get a list of IP and every 15 seconds open a website. How did you do it? What module should I use? Thanks you

Comment: I guess you mean websites over HTTP? The main thing to clarify is do you mean a different website IP address every 15 seconds, or a different source IP address (i.e. client IP address)? If you mean the client IP address you can't do that unless the host you're running on has lots of addresses.

Comment: thanks dear Cartoo. I want to write this program for a site (target) and I run the program on my pc or my VPS for to open this site every 15 secound :x

Comment: This sounds like it has a malicious intent to me.

Comment: @frb: How do I use `multiprocessing`'s remote capabilities on about 17000 computers that are only listening to `ssh` on port 31337 when about 90% of them will fail at any given time? :)

Comment: Yeah, may be you are trying to increase the view of that site. Though I don't know the answer but I want to and would request if anyone can help with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking how to make sure you fire off one connection every 15 seconds, even though it may take a few seconds (maybe even longer than 15) for each one, that's easy. Since you're only making one connection every 15 seconds, there's really no reason not to just spawn a thread for each one.

So:

```
def connectToSiteFunction(ip):
    # your code to bind ip (if it's a source) or connect to it (if it's a dst) 
    # and do your thing here

def connectAndWait():
    for ip in ips:
        t = threading.Thread(target=connectToSiteFunction, args=(ip,))
        yield t
        t.start()
        os.sleep(15)

threads = [t for t in connectAndWait()]
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

If you're talking about destination IPs, and you want to know how to use a different one for each request… well, you usually just modify the URL. Something like this:

```
def connectToSiteFunction(ip):
    url = 'http://{}/path/to/page.html'.format(ip)
    # now open url as normal
```

If you're asking how to bind a source address with your chosen URL-downloading library, you'd have to tell us which library, but: Either the library will have a parameter for it, or it will have a way for you to specify a `socket` factory, or it will be impossible (unless you want to monkeypatch `socket.socket` with your own factory). If it lets you specify a `socket` factory, the way to do it is this:

```
def make_socket_factory(srcip):
    def socket_factory():
        s = socket.socket()
        s.bind((srcip, 0))
        return s
    return socket_factory
```

Then just pass in `make_socket_factory(srcip)` as the factory.

If you want to know how to download a URL in the first place… there are a lot of ways to do that, from the stdlib `urllib2` to `requests` and `pycurl` to `twisted`, and there are already plenty of answers on SO (and elsewhere) comparing and contrasting them.